# IIS 7.5 front end with SQL Server 2008 R2 back end. How to use app pool domain account to connect to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

Ok, I noticed a lot of questions close to what I am doing, but none of them seem to handle what I am looking for.

Here is what I am trying to do.  I have two servers on say the happy domain.  One being IIS 7.5 and the other being SQL Server 2008 R2. Both being windows 2008 R2 server on the happy domain. The application is called `newapp` and the application pool is `newpool`

I created an active directory account called `app1` on the happy domain.

I put `happy/app1` in application pool identity for the app pool `newpool`. I give it access to the server and I give it DBA owner access to the SQL Server database.

Developers have integrated security set to true and sspi. Shouldn't that make it use the `apppool` account to connect to the SQL Server database?

At the moment I get `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`:

> *Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON*

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must enable an authentication method *within the application itself* that establishes an identity, such as Windows Integrated Authentication. It isn't a matter of the identity running the application pool.

It appears you have anonymous access enabled on this website, hence the attempt to log into SQL Server with "NT AUTHORITY/ANONYMOUS LOGON."

Comment: Ok, but I don't want it to connect as the user who connects to the website.  I want it to connect using the "service" account.   Or the account that the apppool is running under.   I see many ways of doing if the application and SQL are on the same box, but do to security issues we don't put both on the same box.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but give this a try....configure your app to use Windows Authentication, but ensure the application has Impersonation turned *off*. I *believe* that will pass the AppPool identity to SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Since account is specified in application pool, just go to IIS->Authentication-> Annonymous Authentication-> Edit

Then select Application Pool identity instead of specific account. This will ensure that application will be run under domain account in Application pool